# how to encode json from array push?

Tags: php, json

i had this php code :

```
<?php
    include "../mainmenu/koneksi.php";
    // Start with the list of animals
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM data_binatang";
    $rows = array();
    $res = mysql_query($sql);
    for($i=0; $i<mysql_num_rows($res); ++$i){
        $row1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res);
        $id_binatang = $row1['id_binatang'];
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM data_waktu_vaksinasi WHERE id_binatang = $id_binatang AND (status_vaksin = 'belum' OR status_vaksin IS NULL) ORDER BY tanggal_vaksin ASC LIMIT 1";
        $res2 = mysql_query($sql);
        $row2 = mysql_fetch_assoc($res2);
        $arr[$id_binatang] = array();
        array_push($arr[$id_binatang], $row1['nama_binatang'], $row1['id_user'], $row1['jenis_binatang'], $row1['ras_binatang'], $row1['foto_binatang'], $row2['nama_vaksin'], $row2['id_data_waktu_vaksinasi'], $row2['status_vaksin'], $row2['tanggal_vaksin'], $row2['tanggal_datang']);
    }

    echo "RESULT:";
    echo "<table border=1><tr><th>id binatang</th><th>nama binatang</th><th>id user</th><th>jenis binatang</th><th>ras binatang</th><th>foto binatang</th><th>nama vaksin</th><th>id data waktu vaksin</th><th>status vaksin</th><th>tanggal vaksin</th><th>tanggal datang</th></tr>";
    foreach($arr as $key => $val){
        echo "<tr><td>$key</td><td>".implode("</td><td>", $val)."</td></tr><br>";
    }

?>
```

and here's the [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5i2aN.png)

now i want to generate the table into json, but i don't know what to put inside the json encode, i tried:

```
echo '{"data_vaksinasi_menu":'.json_encode($arr[$id_binatang]).'}';
```

but instead it gave me null

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo json_encode(array('data_vaksinasi_menu' => $arr));
```

Comment: nice! thank you, now i want to put the name for every value. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: the json only generate the value, but i want to generate the key too

Comment: Hope you need this If I understands you. update the push in for loop like below.

    array_push($arr[$id_binatang]['data_vaksinasi_menu'], $row1['nama_binatang'], $row1['id_user'], $row1['jenis_binatang'], $row1['ras_binatang'], $row1['foto_binatang'], $row2['nama_vaksin'], $row2['id_data_waktu_vaksinasi'], $row2['status_vaksin'], $row2['tanggal_vaksin'], $row2['tanggal_datang']);